# Change default widgets of Django to custom ones

Tags: django, forms, monkeypatching

My usecase: I want to use a different DateInput. But I want to reduce code duplication. I want all forms, which don't explicitly want a different DateInput widget, to use my custom widget.

Any change to solve this without monkey patching?

Example

models.py:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    date=models.DateField()
```

forms.py:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=MyModel
```

The above code should use my custom widget. I don't want to change the above models.py and forms.py, since there are many.

Comment: Take a look at [django-floppyforms](https://github.com/gregmuellegger/django-floppyforms). If you don't use the app itself, you could at least get some inspiration for how they handle it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think you can get this working with your exact code listed above.

Without hacking django, essentially there are 2 parts to this. The first is creating a custom **form field**, and the second is defaulting your custom **model field** to your newly created form field.

To create your custom Form Field, you could override the existing django forms.DateField and update the widget.

```
# form_fields.py
from django.forms import DateField
from myapp.widgets import MyWidget

class MyDateFormField(DateField):
    widget = MyWidget
```

And then after you have your form field created, you're going to have to override the django model field to default to your new form field

```
# fields.py
from django.db.models import DateField
from myapp.form_fields import MyDateFormField

class MyDateField(DateField):
    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        defaults = {'form_class': MyDateFormField}
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        return super(DateField, self).formfield(**defaults)
```

You would then have your custom model field, which you would need to slightly change your code to use.

```
from myapp.fields import MyDateField

class MyModel(models.Model):
    date=MyDateField()
```

It's not exactly what you were asking for (have to change the model field), but hopefully this gets you in the right direction.

Comment: Your first sentence answers my question: "Unfortunately, I don't think you can get this working with your exact code listed above.". The lines following the first line are the answer to a different question. I guess it will help some people. Thank you. (Short answer: it is not possible without monkey patching).

Comment: I am currently employed to this same task, could you please detail further " defaulting your custom model field". Can't I change default field by overriding django.db.models.Model class?

Answer (score -1):

1. Create your field
2. Create form that will use this field by default
3. import this form instead of default form, when you use it

If you're using it in admin:

4. create your own ModelAdmin that will use your form by default
5. use that instead of default ModelAdmin.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Your answer explains how to use a custom widget. I want to use the custom widget everywhere without modifying the code. I want to change the default of django itself.

Comment: So I think it's not possible without monkey-patching